# NextJS Link with anchor navigates to the site's root

Tags: next.js, next.js13, next-link

I'm new to NextJS, and I'm working on a page that's under a /security/ path.

On the file /app/security/page.jsx I have a simple link to an anchor tag

```
<Link href="#data-storage" scroll={false}>Data Storage</Link>
```

Clicking this link will navigate to /#data-storage instead of /security/#data-storage.

Changing the Link to an "a" works as expected. Why is Link doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an absolute URL instead of a relative URL:

```
<Link href="/security/#data-storage" scroll={false}>Data Storage</Link>
```

This is because the `Link` component in `Next.js v13` uses the HTML5 History API to navigate between pages